# force different npm modules to share same dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Sorry for the NOOB question, I am new to npm and front end development.

I have a library (A) which needs to be a singleton but has an init to pass start up config.  I also have a library B which has library A as a dependency.  In my web client I need to reference library A directly and also library B.  I init library A in my web client.

From my investigation it looks like my web client and library B are using there own copy of library A and therefore because library A only works as a singleton, library B's call to library A is failing with `undefined`.

```
library A

library B
 |----library A

web-client
 |----library A
 |----library B
       |----library A
```

In my web client library A and B are referenced in package.json.  My question is is there a way to tell library B to use the library A the web-client has referenced directly?

Comment: is the version of library A the same in both library B & your web client's package.json? Also, what version of npm are you using?

Comment: @DerekNguyen they weren't but even after updating them to the same I was still having issues.  estus `npm dedupe` command did the trick.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in NPM 3 and higher.

One copy of `library A` will be installed and will be used by both `library B` and `web-client`, as long as `library A` version constraints match in `library B` and `web-client` dependencies.

If version constraints don't match, `library B` and `web-client` will have their own copies of `library A`.

It's possible to get multiple copies of `library A` if project dependencies weren't installed simultaneously.

In this case

```
npm dedupe
```

or removing `node_modules` and reinstalling dependencies with

```
npm i
```

will help.